# When does Windows 10 delete memory dumps when set to auto deletion of memory dumps when disk space is low?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bsod, dump

I guess the main question is - what is Windows 10 defining as "low" here? I work in support, and I often have users tell me that the MEMORY.DMP file isn't there, even when they saw Windows write it. I assume this is due to low hard drive space, since most of my users have laptops and probably run right at the edge of full, so Windows is probably deleting the file as soon as it reboots. However, I have no guideline to give them when telling them how much space to keep open on their drive. 100 GB? 10%? I Googled around and couldn't find anything like an official answer.

Answer (score 2):

The formula Windows uses for calculating when you're in low space is:

Free Space (MB) < MAX(600, 10*√(total disk size in MB))

Comment: Welcome to [su]! Do you have a source for this? Which versions of Windows does this apply to?

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @jpaugh I work at Microsoft on the filesystems team and this applies to the latest version.

Comment: @DavidPostill this answers a portion of the OP's question, "I have no guideline to give them when telling them how much space to keep open on their drive"

Comment: @user1574981 So if you are going to quote some formula then at least provide a reference - if it is not documented then why should we take your word for it?

Comment: @DavidPostill, you're right I should provide documentation, but posting official documentation is more difficult than you might expect. I guess you could run an experiment on your own machine and verify that the information I've given you is correct. I apologize for the lack of verifiability otherwise.

Comment: "[...] documentation is more difficult than you might expect." No, it's exactly as difficult as I expect. That's why I was hoping you were sitting on a reference. :-) Thanks for the info, though!